# Help understanding cut command in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cut

In a bash script, there are the following 2 lines:

```
ipaddr=$0
segments=`echo $ipaddr | cut --delimiter=. --fields=2-3 --output-delimiter=/`
```

I do not know how to interpret the second line where the variable `$segments` is created.

How does this part work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the breakdown.

The echo will output whatever is in the variable $ipaddr

```
echo $ipaddr
```

This is then [piped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) through to the following command.

Cut can be used to delimit (i.e. split into parts) a string. A parameter to cut tells it where to "cut" the string (here it is on points, so if the IP address is of the following format: "198.51.100.0", it will be split into 198 51 100 and 0). Another parameter tells it which parts, of the string that it has cut, it should take. Here it is parts 2 and 3. In the example ip I gave above, this would give 51 and 100. A final paramter tells it to put together the parts it has selected (parts 2 and 3) with a new delimiter (here a slash). The result would be 51/100.

```
cut --delimiter=. --fields=2-3 --output-delimiter=/
```

The result of all this (in my example being 51/100) is saved inside the segments variable. Whenever you run the following:

```
somevar=`somecommand`
```

whatever is between the backticks is executed. What it returns is passed to the left side of the equals sign.

Comment: `$somevar=\`somecommand\`` should not have a dollar sign in the LHS.  I tried to edit the post but lack the privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Let's dissect this.

> `echo $ipaddr`

Assuming this is an IPv4 address written in decimal, this gives something like 100.90.80.70. This we pipe to

> `cut --delimiter=. --fields=2-3 --output-delimiter=/

This will chop each of its input lines (just one in this case) at '.', so we now have 100 90 80 70. It selects fields 2 to 3 from here, i.e. we keep 90 80. This is written out, separated by '/'. Result is 90/80, as a rapid experiment shows.

The above mostly from looking at the manual page for cut(1), my memory isn't *that* good.